# How to inherit grid from menu/menubutton

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the class `material_menu` to inherit `Menubutton`'s methods `grid` and `grid_forget` so that I can show or hide the widget. I have no idea which class I should inherit and how to modify the function `set_state`. Please help, suggest some examples.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class material_menu():
def __init__(self, name):
    menubutton = ttk.Menubutton(text=name)
    menubutton.menu = Menu(menubutton)
    menubutton["menu"] = menubutton.menu
    dict = {}
    for sheet_name in ["Menu A", "Menu B", "MenuC"]:
        dict[sheet_name] = Menu(menubutton.menu)
        menubutton.menu.add_cascade(label=sheet_name, menu=dict[sheet_name])
        for material in ["item1", "item2", "item3"]:
            dict[sheet_name].add_command(label=material, command=lambda sheet_name=sheet_name, material=material: test(sheet_name, material))

    def set_state(self, state, row):
        if state==0:
            menubutton.grid_forget()
        else:
            menubutton.grid(column=0, row=row, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

def test(sheet_name, material):
    print(sheet_name)
    print(material)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Tk()
    a=material_menu("Menubutton")
    a.set_state(1, 0)
    win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with inheriting tkinter methods, neither this is a problem with tkinter.

In the above code `set_state` is a function *under* `__init__`. That's why you can't use it outside `__init__`'s scope. If you want to use `set_state` as a method to `material_menu` class;

1. You must first reverse the indentation in your `set_state` so that
   it is defined in the same level as `__init__`.
2. You then need to rename "`menubutton`" to "`self.menubutton`" so
   that it is no longer a variable but rather a class attribute of
   `material_menu`. You should rename 9 in total.

Your code should look exactly like:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class material_menu():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.menubutton = ttk.Menubutton(text=name)
        self.menubutton.menu = Menu(self.menubutton)
        self.menubutton["menu"] = self.menubutton.menu
        dict = {}
        for sheet_name in ["Menu A", "Menu B", "MenuC"]:
            dict[sheet_name] = Menu(self.menubutton.menu)
            self.menubutton.menu.add_cascade(label=sheet_name, menu=dict[sheet_name])
            for material in ["item1", "item2", "item3"]:
                dict[sheet_name].add_command(label=material, command=lambda sheet_name=sheet_name, material=material: test(sheet_name, material))

    def set_state(self, state, row):
        if state==0:
            self.menubutton.grid_forget()
        else:
            self.menubutton.grid(column=0, row=row, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

def test(sheet_name, material):
    print(sheet_name)
    print(material)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Tk()
    a=material_menu("Menubutton")
    a.set_state(1, 0)
    win.mainloop()
```